# как при переборе массива "foreach" убрать последнюю запятую

Tags: php, foreach

Есть такой код

```
foreach( $regions as $region ){
    echo $region->name . ", "; //Добавляю запятую
}
```

Получаю в итоге: Город, Район, Микрорайон,

Как убрать последнюю запятую?

Правильно ли это?

```
foreach( $regions as $region ){
    $region_name[] = $region->name;
}
echo "г. " . $region_name[0] . ", " . $region_name[1] . ", " . $region_name[2];`
```

Comment: Функция `trim()` со вторым параметром. Или выдернуть все `name` и использовать `implode`. Или проверка - последний/не последний элемент массива.

Comment: @u_mulder Подскажи как выдернуть все name?

Comment: Добавить каждый нейм в массив.

Comment: @u_mulder Правильно ли я сделал?

Comment: Ваша поправка - решение, но в нём никакой гибкости. Если вы решите добавить в regions ,Дом, Квартира. То придётся дописывать код.

Comment: @vasenev.ea а если добавлять не чего не буду то все правильно верно?

Comment: @МихаилВолков Это называется hard code. На мой взгляд так не правильно. Т.к. создаётся дополнительный массив и ручной вывод элементов. Старайтесь писать код, гибкий к изменениям.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Указанную задачу можно решить функцией [array_map](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php) в сочетании с функцией [implode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php). Использовать foreach нет необходимости для конкатенации определенного параметра в массиве обьектов.

```
echo implode(',', array_map(function($region) { return $region->name; }, $regions));
```

Answer (score 0):

Не обязательно использовать foreach.
Если это php, то можно использовать:

```
$str = implode (",\r\n", $regions);
```

Но нужно переопределить метод __ToString();

Вот подробнее о функции:
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php

А если Вы всё же хотите использовать foreach, то придётся вот так:

```
  $i = 0; 
  foreach ($regions as $region ) {
    if ($i == 0) {
        echo $region->name . ", ";
     } else if ($i == $len - 1) {
        echo $region->name;
     }
        $i++;
   }
```

Comment: У автора `$regions` это массив **объектов**

Comment: Так ведь implode  и принимает массив. string implode ( string $glue , array $pieces )

Comment: Еще раз не массив **строк**, а массив **объектов**. А `implode` все объекты приведет к строкам, что неверно

Comment: @vasenev.ea Мне кажется ваш код более громоздким но все таки спасибо скажите я исправил вопрос в котором указал как я сделал правильно ли или ваше решение правильнее?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov согласен, не углядел.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov ты не понял если в объекте сделать `public function __toString() { return $this->name; }` а потом `implode(',', array<object>);` то все будет ок. Я бы сказал даже более локонично и грамотнее.

Comment: p.s. А автору, если предполагается использовать счетчик то лучше заюзать `for` но тут и `for` и счётчик `i` не нужен, а просто сравнеение `array_key_last($regions) == $keyRegion`

Comment: @Naumov Посмотрите историю правок. Изначально об этой функции ничего не говорилось

Comment: А автору ответа не плохо было бы в двух словах описать, что это за функция и зачем она нужна